# How to perform GroupBy Sum query on a list?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, group-by, aggregate

**Background**

I have worked with C#.Net + LINQ wherever possible and trying my hand at C++ development for a project I am involved. Of course, I fully realize that C# and C++ are two different worlds.

**Question**

I have an `std::list<T>` where `T` is a struct as follows:

```
struct SomeStruct{
    int id;
    int rate;
    int value;
};
```

I need to get a result of group by `rate` and sum of `value`. How can I perform GroupBy Sum aggregate function on this list?

Example:

```
SomeStruct s1;
SomeStruct s2;
SomeStruct s3;

s1.id=1;
s1.rate=5;
s1.value=100;

s2.id=2;
s2.rate=10;
s2.value=50;

s3.id=3;
s3.rate=10;
s3.value=200;

std::list<SomeStruct> myList;
myList.push_front(s1);
myList.push_front(s2);
myList.push_front(s3);
```

With these inputs I would like to get following output:

```
rate|value
----|-----
   5|  100
  10|  250
```

I found a few promising libs such as [CINQ](https://kevinchen.co/projects/cinq/) and [cppitertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools). But I couldn't fully understand as I lack sufficient knowledge. It would be great if someone guide me to right direction, I am more than willing to learn new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing a Group-By sum is relatively straightforward:

```
using sum_type = int; // but maybe you want a larger type
auto num_groups = max_rate + 1;
std::vector<sum_type> rate_sums(num_groups); // this is initialized to 0
for(const auto& s : myList) {
    rate_sums[s.rate] += s.value;
}
```

this is when the `rate` values are within `0` and `max_rate`, and `max_rate` is not too large relative to `myList.size()`; otherwise the memory use might be excessive (and you'll have some overhead initializing the vector).

If the `rate` values are scattered over a large range relative to `myList.size()`, consider using an `std::unoredered_map` instead of an `std::vector`).

The code above can also be parallelized. The way to parallelize it depends on your hardware, and there are all sorts of libraries to help you do this. In C++20 there might be [language facilities for parallelization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism).

Remember, though, that linked lists are rather slow to work with, because you have to dereference an arbitrary address to get from one element to the next. If you can get your input in an `std::vector` or a plain array, that would be faster; and if you can't, it's probably worthless to bother with parallelization.